# Visual Studio - Test case run status after restarting VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I have a large number of Automated Coded UI test cases that I set to execute overnight. Last I checked, more than 300 had passed out of 800+. However when I checked the status in the morning, turns out my computer switched off due to some kind of system update. Now when I open the solution and see the status of the test cases, I am only seeing them as "Not Run" rather than "Passed" or "Failed".

Is there any way I can retrieve the test cases status before my machine shut itself off?

Comment: you won't be able to retrieve the old status but you can check your test result folder and review it to see which tests run and which didn't